# Convert pcm data to wav file with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

Is it possible to use the NAudio API to convert a raw pcm file to Wav format. I can see there is
an Mp3FileReader that allows mp3 to wav but we need to convert raw audio data files.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naudio page on github has an example about this [This Page](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RawSourceWaveStream.md)

```
var path = "example.pcm";
var s = new RawSourceWaveStream(File.OpenRead(path), new WaveFormat(8000,1));
var outpath = "example.wav";
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outpath, s);
```